# Hooking AMPL with Matlab using amplfunc and spamfunc

Tags: matlab, optimization, ampl

I'm interested in hooking up AMPL with Matlab to obtain objective values, gradients, and Jacobians to test ideas for optimization algorithms on a wide set of problems. I'm aware that I can use amplfunc.mex or spamfunc.mex to do this; however, I'm having trouble compiling the .mex files using the old netlib files on Windows. The link also given in a previous question:

[Using MATLAB with AMPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296567/using-matlab-with-ampl)

is outdated. Does anyone know where I can obtain these .mex files or offer any alternative solutions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mex files amplfunc.c and spamfunc.c are still available at http://www.ampl.com/netlib/ampl/solvers/examples. We aren't aware of a reason why these wouldn't compile, but if you are having trouble you could write to the AMPL user forum, ampl@googlegroups.com.  Be sure to explain which function you are using and to give the complete text of any error messages you see.